# Getting bean based on key in Spring4 Annotationbased

Tags: java, spring

I had configure Spring 4 with `WebApplicationInitializer`. There are two service named `Item1Service` and `Item2Service`.

But In controller I need to find one service based on key provided by user.
If there were xml based configuration then I can get by id.

But how I can get `AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext` object in controller, so that I can get my bean based on key.

I have used 
`@Service(value="item1")` and `@Service(value="item2")`

Kindly help me out on this

Comment: And there is no difference between XML and java configuration... It still is an `ApplicatinContext` with the same `getBean` methods... SO why wouldn't it work.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to autowire your application context into your controller (or wherever you are performing the lookup) so that you can then call the `getBean` method with whatever input the user provided.

```
@Autowired
private ApplicationContext appContext;
```

then in your method:

```
MyService s = appContext.getBean(input);
```

Answer (score 0):

If it's only a couple of implementations you have to choose from, then you have one more option. Autowire all services in the controller and switch at runtime based on the key. (**Note:** I will not prefer this, if the service implementation count exceeds 3. It will make your code unreadable as well as it will unnecessarily create service reference variables in controller)

> ```
> @Autowired @Qualifier("item1")
>     ItemService item1Service;
>
> @Autowired @Qualifier("item2")
>     ItemService item2Service;
> ```